# Как можно заменит "янв на Jan" при установки даты времени

Tags: c++, qt

Написал следующий код.

```
void SettingsClock::on_dateTimeEdit_dateTimeChanged(const QDateTime &dateTime)
{

    //system("date -s \"19 APR 2015 11:14:00\"");

    QString datetime;

    datetime = "date -s ";

    datetime += "\"";

    datetime += dateTime.toString("dd MMM yy hh:mm:ss");

    datetime += "\"";

    qDebug() << datetime;

    const char *data = datetime.toAscii();

    qDebug() << data;

    system(data);

    system("hwclock -w");
}
```

Ничего особенного, просто установка часов. Но когда пытаюсь установить часы получаю `date -s "02 янв 00 00:00:00"`. Вот этот `янв` портит все. Линукс не хочет его принимать пишет

> invalid date '02 \321\217\320\275\320\262 00 00:00:00'

Как можно заменит янв на Jan?

Решение если кому надо:

```
   QString datetime;
   datetime = "date -s ";
   datetime += "\"";
   QLocale loc(QLocale::English, QLocale::UnitedStates);
   datetime += loc.toString(dateTime, "dd MMM yy hh:mm:ss");
   datetime += "\"";
   const char *data = datetime.toAscii();
   system(data);
   system("hwclock -w");
```

Comment: А к переменным тоже не стоит из двух потоков обращаться - с этим как сладили?

Comment: А какое решение вы считаете **классическим**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что у Вас используется неправильная локализация. Вам нужно ее установить вполне конкретной. Смотрите пример:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QLocale>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug()<<QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd MMM yy hh:mm:ss"); // неправильный вывод

    QLocale loc(QLocale::English, QLocale::UnitedStates);
    qDebug()<<loc.toString(QDateTime::currentDateTime(), "dd MMM yy hh:mm:ss"); // вывод в американской локализации

    return a.exec();
}
```

Вообще, данный вопрос является дубликатом вот этого: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771693/how-to-display-a-qdate-month-with-a-different-locale-than-system)